# Derive one induction variant from another

Tags: logic, induction

I need help regarding the following exercise:

> Derive the variant
>   $$[\forall n:((\forall m < n: \varphi (m)) \Rightarrow \varphi (n))] \Rightarrow \forall n: \varphi(n)$$
>   of mathematical induction from the variant
>   $$[\psi(0) \land \forall n:(\psi(n) \Rightarrow \psi(n+1))] \Rightarrow \forall n:\psi(n)$$
>   where $n,m \in \mathbb N_0$.

My attempt:

Define $$\psi(n) :\Leftrightarrow \varphi(n-1)\land \forall m < n: \varphi(m)$$

And here's the problem. I can't plug $0$ into $\varphi$ since it is only defined for natural numbers $\geq 0$.
However, if I somehow could work around that I think I would get the first variant. Am I correct and how can I fix my attempt?

Update: I tried with $\psi(n) :\Leftrightarrow \forall m < n: \varphi(m)$ but wasn't really able to derive the first scheme.

Comment: You have to apply math induction to the property $\varphi(n)$ : $(∀z)(z ≤ n \to \psi (z))$.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I actually do, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $\psi (n) = \forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)$

With that, the basic proof outline becomes this:

You have the general principle of weak mathematical induction, which says that for any $\psi (n)$ that:

$$[\psi(0) \land \forall n:(\psi(n) \Rightarrow \psi(n+1))] \Rightarrow \forall n:\psi(n)$$

so with $\psi (n) = \forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)$ that becomes:

$$[(\forall m \leq 0 : \varphi(m)) \land \forall n: ((\forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)) \Rightarrow (\forall m \leq n+1 : \varphi(m)))] \Rightarrow \forall n:\forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)$$

OK, so that's the premise of your argument.  The conclusion is the general principle of strong mathematical induction:

$$[\forall n:((\forall m < n: \varphi (m)) \Rightarrow \varphi (n))] \Rightarrow \forall n : \varphi(n)$$

OK, since the goal is a conditional, do a conditional proof:

Assume

$$[\forall n:((\forall m < n: \varphi (m)) \Rightarrow \varphi (n))]$$

and try and get to

$$\forall n : \varphi(n)$$

Once you have the above assumption, you want to prove two things:

Base: $$(\forall m \leq 0 : \varphi(m))$$

Step: $$\forall n: ((\forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)) \Rightarrow (\forall m \leq n+1 : \varphi(m)))$$

The base trivially follows from your assumption: since there are no number smaller than 0, the statement $$\forall m < 0: \varphi (m)$$ is trivially true, and hence $\varphi(0)$ is true, and hence the base is true.

For the step, do a general conditional proof, i.e. assume n to be some number, assume  $$\forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)$$ and try to get to $$\forall m \leq n+1 : \varphi(m))$$

Again, using the original assumption, this should not be hard.

OK, so now we have the base and the step, so using the premise of your argument, you get $$\forall n:\forall m \leq n : \varphi(m)$$ and from there, your original goal of $$\forall n : \varphi(n)$$ easily follows.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer!